# Android ninepatch image error in eclipse 3.5.2

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm using Eclipse 3.5.2 on win7 with latest sdk update. Every time i
create ninepatch image and copy it into drawable folders, the project
becomes error, seems that the file cause error and not supported. I use photoshop to create PNG-24 image then edit it using draw9patch tool.

Here is my draw9patch screenshoot : http://londatiga.net/draw9.jpg.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify stretch regions on the top and left borders of the image (no black markers there), android compiler can't process the image, that's why you get the errors. Try adding a black region on top and left sides.

Comment: ok it works now, thanx alot. Btw, whats the differents between a dot marker and line marker?

Comment: You're welcome, just do not forget to accept the answer ;)
There is no difference actually, drawing a line on the top or left you specify a region that would be stretched. If you draw only dot the 1px wide region would be stretched.

Comment: Okay thanx for your explanation. Just accepted your answer, sorry i'm new to stackoverflow, have to read the faq to find how to accept answer :D.